# (JAVA) If replacing previous if statement

Tags: java, android, android-studio, if-statement

Quick question. I have the following code:

```
//Cookie
if (mType.getText().toString().toLowerCase().contains("Cookie")) {
    mResults.setText(mType.getText().toString().replaceAll("(?i)\\bCookie\\b", "Dough"));
}

//Cola
if (mType.getText().toString().toLowerCase().contains("Cola")) {
    mResults.setText(mType.getText().toString().replaceAll("(?i)\\bCola\\b", "Sprite"));
}
```

I have a script which allows me to replace certain words from user input. When a user inputs the word "Cookie", the script replaces the word with "Dough". If, however, the user types in "Cookie Cola", the script only replaces the word "Cola" with "Sprite" and discards the previous if statement which replaces the word "Cookie".

So, how can I create a script which allows me to replace multiple words from input without discarding previous if statements?

Comment: why would `anything.toLowerCase()` contain `Cookie` or `Cola` if it's all lowercase?

Comment: Why are the if statements even there?  If a pattern doesn't match then nothing is replaced, the if isn't needed.

Comment: Hello @GabeSechan, thanks for your comment! I understand your question, however, I have no idea what else I should use.. I'm a beginner at this..

Answer (score 1):

You can just store it into a variable.

like:

```
String value = (mType.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

if(value.contains("soda")) { value = value.replaceAll("soda","cola"); }
if(...) {...}
```

But.  Technically you are doing more work than necessary.  You can chain your replacements.

```
String value = (mType.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
value = value.replaceAll("soda","cola").replaceAll("...","...")... //Etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question-  in both ifs, you're calling replace on mType.getText().  But you aren't changing that value.  So you're doing the second replace on the original string.  Here's how the code should look like:

```
String text = mType.getText().toString();
text = text.replaceAll("(?i)\\bCookie\\b", "Dough");
text = text.replaceAll("(?i)\\bCola\\b", "Sprite"));
mResults.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Chaining together multiple `String.replaceAll()` statements can achieve the same result without the need for `if` statements. For example

```
String result = mType.getText.toString().toLowerCase();
result = result.replaceAll("cola", "sprite")
        .replaceAll("cookie", "dough"); // And so on...
mResults.setText(result);
```